# The type 'NDArray' exists in both 'NumSharp.Core, Version=0.20.4.0, 'NumSharp.Lite, Version=0.1.7.0

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to use NumSharp.Core Version=0.20.4.0 (particularly NumSharp.Bitmap), but when I install it, i get this error

`The type 'NDArray' exists in both 'NumSharp.Core, Version=0.20.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' and 'NumSharp.Lite, Version=0.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'`

I'm not using `NumSharp.Lite, Version=0.1.7.0` (I don't even have installed it), but I figured some packages I use do call NumSharp.Lite. These Packages are:

- SharpCV
- SciSharp.TensorFlow
- TensorFlow.NET

Is there a way to be able to use NumSharp.Bitmap in this scenario?

Is it posible to force all dependences to use NumSharp.Core instead of Numsharp.Lite?

I am working on Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.5.4, on Windows 10 home edition.

Thank you!

---

**EDIT**

I tryed to downgrade the three packages to the last version they used NumSharp.Core, unfortunately, this leads to other kind of errors, like functions that haven't been implemented on those versions, so that's not a viable alternative.

For the moment I've been able to work without NumSharp.Bitmap by doing everything by brute force, but it is not the ideal.

Comment: The easiest way might be to copy the source for NumSharp.Bitmap into your project, but that could get messy if it has lots of other dependencies from .Core that clash with .Lite. It does seem silly that there's no way to include both Core and Lite though for dependencies; as far as I can tell you can't do it with .NET's binding redirects.

Comment: https://github.com/SciSharp/NumSharp/issues/399